# Comparar 2 columnas de 2 tablas diferentes en la Base de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

estoy intentando comparar 2 columnas `(difficulty, difficulty_student)` de 2 tablas diferentes **(EXERCISES, ANSWERS)** de la base de datos Mysql y crear una nueva columna en la tabla **ANSWERS** comparando ambas tablas con un tipo de dato VARCHAR (YES o NO). Si el usuario ha cambiado la dificultad del ejercicio, en la celda deberá aparecer un '*YES*', si no se ha cambiado, la celda será '*NO*'.

Me gustaría comparar la columna ‘`difficulty`’ de la tabla **EXERCISES** y ' `difficulty_student` ' de la tabla **ANSWERS**, y almacenarla en '`difficulty_change`' de la tabla **ANSWERS**. Pero el problema es que la columna '`dificulty_change`' no puede comparar valores hasta que el usuario presione el botón '`submit`', que es cuando ingresan el valor *YES* o *NO* en la columna '`difficulty_student`' y así poder compararlo con '`difficulty`' de la tabla **EXERCISES**.

Estas son mis 2 tablas.

```
CREATE TABLE exercises (
    exercise_id INT,
    difficulty INT
    PRIMARY KEY(exercise_id)
);

CREATE TABLE answers(
    exercise_id_fk INT,
    student_id INT,
    difficulty_change VARCHAR(3),
    difficulty_student INT,
    choice_answer INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(exercise_id_fk) REFERENCES exercises(exercise_id)
);
```

Esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora pero no se en qué tabla esta guardando ‘`difficulty_change`’. Me gustaría guardarla en la tabla **ANSWERS**. me podéis ayudar?

```
SELECT e.difficulty, a.difficulty_student, 
case when e.difficulty = a.difficulty_student then 'NO' else 'YES' 
         END  as difficulty_change
FROM exercises e 
INNER JOIN answers a  on e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk;
```

Aquí muestro un ejemplo de como me gustaría que quedasen las tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando hacer un programa en el que el usuario tiene una serie de ejercicios, y cada uno de ellos tiene un desplegable de opciones donde aparece el nivel de dificultad del ejercicio. Por defecto, el desplegable de cada ejercicio tiene su nivel de dificultad asignado, pero el usuario puede cambiarlo si le parece incorrecto. De esta manera, lo cambie o no, su repuesta se guardará en la tabla de la base de datos.

Lo que me gustaría hacer es comparar 2 columnas `(difficulty, difficulty_student)` from 2 different tablas **(EXERCISES, ANSWERS)** y crear una nueva columna en la tabla **ANSWERS** comparando ambas tablas mediante VARCHAR o BOOLEAN (YES or NO). Si el usuario ha cambiado la dificultad del ejercicio, la celda será ‘YES’, si no la ha cambiado, la celda será ‘NO’.

Así es como se ve mi tabla ahora mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende, es confusa porque hablas de un formulario sin explicar más. Tampoco es claro lo que hace tu modelo de datos y en consecuencia ni siquiera se puede saber si es el modelo correcto. En cuanto al dato `YES/NO` que quieres guardar, lo correcto sería usar una columna booleana para guardar `TRUE/FALSE` evitando así errores.  En una columna `VARCHAR` te admitirá cualquier cosa: YSS,  NOO, ABC, NIYESNINO, ETC... En la columna booleana no.

Comment: @A.Cedano, he modificado la pregunta. He añadido más explicación debajo a ver si se entiende. En realidad me da igual si es BOOLEAN o VARCHAR, mientras funciona. De momento no me funciona de ninguna de las maneras

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Deberias hacer un update de esa columna. no pudiste por algo en particular?

Comment: Tan mal formulada está mi pregunta? @gbianchi

Comment: No. Pero siempre se recomienda a los que recien ingresan que lean el recorrido y como preguntar, para aprender a dar formato y tambien en el recorrido se aclara que no funcionamos exactamente igual que SO en ingles por ejemplo. No es por nada en particular, tu pregunta esta bien explicada, solo que como no funcionamos exactamente igual y es tu primera pregunta en ESTE sitio, esta bueno que le pegues una repasada. yo la entiendo tu pregunta y por eso te pregunte, hiciste un update?

Comment: @gbianchi, en realidad vengo de StackOverflow en Inglés, no es mi primera vez en StackOverflow, pero sí es mi primera vez en StackOverflow en Español. Edité la pregunta, eso es update?

Comment: No. ahora te pongo una respuesta.. me referia a que no tenes que hacer un select.. tenes que hacer un update a la tabla que tiene ese campo nuevo... ;).. Y muchos venimos de alla, y las reglas no son exactamente las mismas, como tampoco los motivos de cierre ni varias otras cosas...

Comment: Y bienvenida! espero que te guste y sientas mas a gusto en este sitio ;)

Comment: Ah, pues no he hecho lo del update... puse ese código porque funcionaba pero en realidad no se en qué tabla lo está guardando. Me gustaría guardarlo en la tabla ANSWERS como en la imagen. Gracias :D

Comment: Si he entendido bien la solución es más simple de lo que parece, pero las respuestas parecen complicadas porque no has sigo del todo clara planteando la pregunta. A mi juicio el enfoque correcto sería el siguiente: en el formulario recoger el ID del estudiante y el estado de la dificultad: `TRUE` o `FALSE` (preferible), enviar la información al servidor vía Ajax para que se haga la actualización usando en el `WHERE` el ID del estudiante. La llamada Ajax puede ocurrir cuando el usuario haga un cambio en el select/option que muestra las dificultades. + que nada pareces tener 1problema de enfoque

Comment: ana,@A.Cedano tiene razon. me parece que estas mirando mal el problema. Esto ya lo deberias tener guardado al actualizar la respuesta, ya que ahi sabes lo que paso. Si es para actualizar una tabla que ya existe, entonces si sirven las respuestas.

Comment: @A.Cedano, entiendo tu respuesta, pero Victor me ha dado la respuesta con YES o NO que es lo que necesitaba. Aunque solo cambia a YES o NO cuando ejecuto su código en Mysql, me gustaría que pusiese YES o NO directamente cuando le doy a SUBMIT, que es lo que estoy intentando ahora.

Comment: @gbianchi, en realidad la líneas de la tabla ANSWERS no existen hasta que el usuario pulse SUBMIT, que es cuando se recogerán los datos. Y ahí es cuando se comparan en `difficulty_change` las celdas de `difficulty` y `difficulty_student`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola buenos días amiga puedes probar el siguiente query:

**Mysql**

```
UPDATE answers AS A 
INNER JOIN exercises AS E 
ON A.exercise_id_fk = E.exercise_id
SET A.difficulty_change = CASE WHEN E.difficulty = A.difficulty_student 
    THEN 'NO' 
    ELSE 'YES' 
    END
WHERE A.student_id = @IDESTUDIANTE
```

**SQLServer**

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.difficulty_change = CASE WHEN E.difficulty = A.difficulty_student 
    THEN 'NO' 
    ELSE 'YES' 
    END
FROM answers AS A
INNER JOIN exercises AS E 
ON A.exercise_id_fk = E.exercise_id
WHERE A.student_id = @IDESTUDIANTE
```

Espero te sirva la falla es que mediante un **select** no puedes insertar datos en una tabla, debes usar un **update** con **inner join**. Me di cuenta que tampoco estas filtrando por id de estudiante **@IDESTUDIANTE** debes tomar en cuenta eso para que no modifique todos los registros. Agregue la sintaxis en SQLServer para los que estén interesados.

Comment: Hola Victor, he probado tu query pero me sale el siguiente error: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM answers AS A INNER JOIN exercises AS E  ON A.exercise_id_fk = E.exercise_id' at line 6 0.016 sec` no se como solucionarlo

Comment: Ya lo corregi era un error de sintaxis lo que pasa es que lo hice en SQL Server

Comment: Sale ahora este error: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM answers A INNER JOIN exercises E  ON A.exercise_id_fk = E.exercise_id WHERE' at line 6 0.000 sec. No tengo ni idea de porque` :(

Comment: Si ya lo arregle prueba ahora lo que pasa es que lo desarrolle en SQL Server

Comment: He probado tu nuevo código, ahora sale este error: `Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect. 0.000 sec` Quizas deba cambiar mi modo seguro? No se como se hace. Crees que es buena idea Victor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench aqui te muestran como se soluciona ese problema, tiene que ver con tus preferencias.

Comment: Vale, ya he quitado el modo seguro y he probado tu código y no me aparecen más errores :D. Lo único que no funciona, en la columna `difficulty_change` sigue apareciendo `NULL`.

Comment: Quitale el WHERE y prueba otra vez debería actualizar ya lo probé.

Comment: He probado con `UPDATE answer a 
INNER JOIN exercises e  on e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk 
set a.difficulty_change = case 
     when e.difficulty = a.difficulty_student then 'NO' else 'YES' END
where e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk` pero solo cambia a YES o NO cuando ejecuto este código en Mysql, me gustaría que pusiese YES o NO directamente cuando le doy a SUBMIT. Vale, pruebo lo que me dices. Lo puedes editar? Me sale error cuando quito el WHERE y no se si lo estoy haaciendo  bien

Comment: Claro te explico en el WHERE debes filtrar el id del estudiante, sino te va a actualizar todos los registros que tengas así sea un id de estudiante diferente. Lo que debes hacer es agregar ese query a un procedimiento almacenado y consumirlo cuando hagas el SUBMIT enviándole el ID del estudiante como parámetro que en este caso sería @IDESTUDIANTE donde esta variable debe contener el id que le enviaste en el SUBMIT.

Comment: Vale, lo veo dificil de hacer. Quieres que te muestre mi código en php con el Submit?

Comment: Como en el programa tengo un login, cada vez que entre un estudiante, cambia su ID, entonces se debería hacer en php donde esté el Submit?

Comment: Ahorita estoy un poco complicado ya que estoy en el trabajo pero puedes leer estos tutoriales de como hacerlo: https://www.anerbarrena.com/mysql-create-procedure-5346/ y https://donnierock.com/2014/07/14/llamar-a-procedimientos-almacenados-en-php/ espero que te funcionen, desde PHP tu mandas el ID es el deber ser.

Comment: Vale gracias lo leer y probar. No te preocupes, si lo consigo te aviso y sino cuando tengas tiempo te pregunto como se hace. :)

Comment: Esta bien éxitos, espero que puedas solucionarlo.

Comment: Hola Victor, no consigo solucionarlo. En cuanto puedas me hechas una mano para lo último que me falta? Lo de agregar ese query a un procedimiento almacenado y consumirlo cuando haga el SUBMIT enviándole el ID del estudiante como parámetro (@IDESTUDIANTE)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81765/discussion-between-victor-perdomo-and-ana).

Answer (score 0):

El query que mostras, definitivamente hace lo que queres.. ahora, lo unico que tenes que hacer es que ese resultado se grabe en la tabla answers

Este es tu query:

```
SELECT e.difficulty, a.difficulty_student, 
case when e.difficulty = a.difficulty_student then 'NO' else 'YES' 
         END  as difficulty_change
FROM exercises e 
INNER JOIN answers a  on e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk;
```

y lo que necesitamos, es un query que haga un update a la tabla Answers, y cambie justamente ese campo.

```
UPDATE answers aa
SET difficulty_change = (
    Select case when e.difficulty = a.difficulty_student then 'NO' else 'YES' 
FROM exercises e 
INNER JOIN answers a  on e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk
where aa.exercise_id_fk = a.exercise_id_fk)
```

Toma en cuenta un par de cosas:

- No veo una clave primaria en tu tabla answers. Puede que el query anterior falle porque no hay una unica forma de identificar la fila en la tabla answers.
- El query anterior puede llegar a ser lento para algunos casos, salvo que agregues mas clausulas where para buscar exactamente la fila que estas necesitando.
- El campo difficulty_change ya debe existir en la tabla answers

Comment: No he añadido clave primaria en mi tabla ANSWERS porque `exercise_id_fk` es foreign key y no lo veía adecuado, pero quizas lo debería cambiar? El campo `difficulty_change` ya existe en la tabla, acabo de añadir una imagen en mi pregunta para que puedas ver como está mi tabla actualmente. Ahora voy a probar tu código y te cuento. (Los campos que tienen 'NO' los he añadido yo para probar)

Comment: Me sale un error en Mysql cuando pruebo el query que me has escrito. Este es el error: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM exercises e  INNER JOIN answers a  on e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk where ' at line 5 0.000 sec`

Comment: Si pudiera cambiar la dificultad de cada respuesta, entonces si deberia.. si no como es la relacion entre ejercicios y respuestas?

Comment: fijate ahora... no tengo como probar el query esta hecho en el aire

Comment: Tu clave es una combinacion de exercise_id_fk  y student_id..

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error, no se porque gbianchi: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM exercises e  INNER JOIN answers a  on e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk where ' at line 4 0.000 sec`

Comment: Fijate si la otra respuesta te sirve, creo que ahi se ve mas simple